# set Continuous variables in OpenModelica while their status is set to Changeable: false

Tags: python, openmodelica

I have some continuous variables in my model that I would like to change them via `OMPython,` however using `mod.getQuantities()` shows they are not changeable (as below). Is there any way to change their status?

```
{'name': 'roomM.p',
  'changeable': 'false',
  'description': 'Pressure of the fluid',
  'variability': 'continuous',
  'causality': 'local',
  'alias': 'alias',
  'aliasvariable': 'roomM.dynBal.medium.p',
  'start': None},
```